Spark history server unable to load events using spark 3.2.3 or spark 3.5
I have spark history server running on kubernetes.  Its configured to read events from a directory and i see events written there by my spark jobs.  Spark history server does come up but shows no events.  I have browsed questions posted about this issue but was unable to solve the problem.
My Set up:
Spark events are written to a file store with correct uid and gid.  I am able to confirm this by logging into my pod and checking files.  I am able to read the files, write to the directory without a problem.  Set up a spark history server pointing at that directory.  Server comes up clean.  Log shows that its scanning/parsing and finished parsing files in  the correct directory for events yet nothing is displayed.
Appreciate any insight you guys may have.
expecting to see spark events displayed on history server UI.

Did the history server logs mention any spark app id, something like parsing application id spark-xxxxxxxxxxxx or app-xxxxxxxxx? If yes do check incomplete apps in history server UI. At the bottom it will say show incomplete. If this also does not show any apps.
Ensure that spark event log dir in spark-submit & history server conf are same.
